# Bookdown: TOC with html_document2

Tags: r, bookdown

How can I create a single output document with `bookdown`, e.g. using its `bookdown::html_document2` format, and still have a Table of Contents somewhere in the output document?

For example, I check out the content from https://github.com/tidyverse/style, and run

```
Rscript -e "bookdown::render_book('index.Rmd', 'bookdown::html_document2')"
```

Then I get a `_main.html` as desired, with all the text from all chapters, but no TOC is present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the dots (`...`) argument of `bookdown::html_document2` to pass `toc = TRUE` to `rmarkdown::html_document`:

```
Rscript -e "bookdown::render_book('index.Rmd', bookdown::html_document2(toc = TRUE))"
```

Comment: Thanks.  Was missing the fact that I could use `bookdown::html_document2` as a function, not just a string.