# Adding table of content with bookdown::html_document2 in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, bookdown

I'm building a `bookdown::html_document2` with Rstudio and I can't seem to manage to add a table of content using Rstudio.

I've found this question ([Bookdown: TOC with html_document2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48796293/bookdown-toc-with-html-document2)) that is related however I knit my document using the `Knit` button of Rstudio while they are using a command line.  In my case, it produces the error:

```
Error in yaml::yaml.load(string, ...) : 
  Scanner error: mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 4, column 33
Calls: <Anonymous> ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load_utf8 -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

To reproduce the error, try:

```
---
title: "main title"
author: "Me"
date: "September 26, 2018"
output: bookdown::html_document2:
  toc=TRUE
---


# title 1

# tt

# rr 

## rrr
```

in Rstudio and hit `Knit`

Any idea how to make it work?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move the `bookdown::html_document2:` into the next row, and add `toc=TRUE` underneath it. Be carefull for indendation. Check out the full [YAML syntax](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/r-markdown.html).

```
---
title: "main title"
author: "Me"
date: "September 26, 2018"
output:
  bookdown::html_document2:
    toc: true
---


# title 1

# tt

# rr 

## rrr
```

Comment: Please consider turning this into more than just a "read the manual" answer. You could have added some context, like "every new output type should be on its own line, after the call to `output`. You also need to be careful with indentations. You can find out more [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/r-markdown.html). This is how you would implement it:...`.

Comment: @AndyClifton Excellent suggestion! Please feel free to edit my answer (sometimes I just type out answers in a hurry and I definitely agree with you that this particular answer should be improved). Thank you very much!

Comment: oddly hard to find an answer to this question. This answer along with YAML syntax suggestion was perfect